# How to make subheadings?

Tags: sectioning

I need, for some structural elements of the book, to add some information on second line. It should either be information about what this part is ("(essay)" or "(tale)") or some information about a person or place i.e.

> The most remarkable person in the city
>
> John 'J' Johnson

Currently, all ihave managed to come up with, was

```
\newcommand{\chapsubhead}[1]{%
  \\{#1}%
}
```

Which does not exactly do what i want in all cases.

How should it be done/changed?

Upd. Code example:

```
\documentclass{book}

\newcommand{\chapsubhead}[1]{%
  \\{#1}%
}

\begin{document}

\section*{The most remarcable man in town\chapsubhead{John 'Jay' Johnsom}}

John 'Jay'Johnson was the most remarkable man in town, maybe in the
whole country. Just one simple trait among all his qualities would
have set him apart from the rest of unremarcable humanity - and it
did!

Not a single living thing has ever witnessed Jay
farting. Never. Not. One. Time.

\end{document}
```

What i want (very roughly):
[image: Libre Office Writer screenshot]

I have taken liberty of including both types of subheading i want.

Comment: Could you post a full, yet minimal, compilable code?

Comment: Can i post Word screenshot of what i think i need instead?

Comment: Yes, but also  what you've tried, under the form of a minimal code, so we don't have to write everything from scratch. In particular, which class you use, which packages you load, in relation with your problem.

Comment: Done and done; i might as well add that i want first paragraph to be offset as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use commands like in the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}

\newcommand{\chapsubhead}[1]{{\Large #1 \vspace{2ex}}}
\newcommand{\chaptype}[1]{{\Large \itshape (#1) \vspace{2ex}}}
\begin{document}

\section*{The most remarcable man in town}
\chapsubhead{John 'Jay' Johnsom}

John 'Jay'Johnson was the most remarkable man in town, maybe in the
whole country. Just one simple trait among all his qualities would
have set him apart from the rest of unremarcable humanity - and it
did!

Not a single living thing has ever witnessed Jay
farting. Never. Not. One. Time


\section*{The most remarcable man in town}
\chaptype{essay}

John 'Jay'Johnson was the most remarkable man in town, maybe in the
whole country. Just one simple trait among all his qualities would
have set him apart from the rest of unremarcable humanity - and it
did!

Not a single living thing has ever witnessed Jay
farting. Never. Not. One. Time.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: 2 additional questions after this. First: how to ensure first paragraph of actual text is not on the next page after? Second: if no chapter type is specified, how to ensure there is horisontal space in the beginning of the first paragraph (same as the second one etc)?